# Display dots until certain zoom level and then display heatmap

Tags: google-maps-api-3, asp.net-core-mvc

Google Maps API.
I am looking for the best way to display simple dot icons (with changeable colors) that do not resize on zooming.

Instead when zoomed to a certain level, the simple dot icons disappear and a summary icon appears with a number value of each color appears.

I have looked into Marker Icons, but they resize on zoom.
To clarify- The marker resizes in reference to the actual latitude and longitude measurements. It remains the same size in reference to the map screen size.

I am looking for a way for the small dot to remain the same size in reference to the latitude and longitude. I have looked into the circle class and those do not appear to be perfect circles on the map. They have rough edges.

Pictures Below

1.Zoomed In All the way
[image: Zoomed In]
2. Zoomed Out - Circles stay same size in reference to the Lat and Lon
[image: Zoomed Out]
3a. Zoomed Out - Circles disappear and "Summary circles" appear
[image: Zoomed Out Sum]
3b. Zoomed Out - Circles disappear and Heat Map appears
[image: Zoomed Out Sum - HeatMap]

New Code I've Tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var spotsArray = [];

    window.onload = initialize();

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas")
            , {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.roadmap
            , zoom: @Model.StartingZoom
            , disableDefaultUI: true
            , zoomControl: true
            , center: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model.StartingLocation)
            });

        map.addListener('zoom_changed', zoomChange, this);
        dataLayer = new google.maps.Data({
            map: map
        });

        window.setInterval(function () { UpdateData() }, 5000);
    }

    function getScaleSize() {
        var scale = null;
        var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
        switch (mapZoom) {
            case 15:
            case 16:
            case 17:
                scale = 1;
                break;
            case 18: 
                scale = 10;
                break;
            case 19:
            case 20:
            case 21:
            case 22:
                scale = 20;
                break;
            default:
                scale = 0;
        }
        return scale;
    }

        function zoomChange() {
            for (var nIndex = 0; nIndex < spotsArray.length; nIndex++) {
                var Spot = spotsArray[nIndex].Spot;
                var Scale = getScaleSize();
                Spot.icon.scale = Scale;
            }
    }

    function UpdateData() {
        GetJsonData('@Url.Action("GetMapData")'
            ,{}
            ,function(jsonData)
        {
            $(jsonData).each(function (item)
            { AddUpdateSpotOnMap(jsonData[item]) });
        });
        };

    function AddUpdateSpotOnMap(SpotData) {
        //SpotID, Latitude, Longitude, StrokeColor, StrokeOpacity, StrokeWeight, FillColor, FillOpacity

        //Check if in Array
        var inArrayIndex = NaN;
        for (var nIndex = 0; nIndex < spotsArray.length; nIndex++) {
            if (SpotData.spotID == spotsArray[nIndex].SpotID) {
                inArrayIndex = nIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isNaN(inArrayIndex) == false) {
            //Update Color
            spotsArray[inArrayIndex].Spot.setOptions({ StrokeColor: SpotData.strokeColor, StrokeOpacity: SpotData.strokeOpacity, StrokeWeight: SpotData.strokeWeight, FillColor: SpotData.fillColor, FillOpacity: SpotData.fillOpacity });
        }
        else {

            var Spot = new google.maps.Marker(
                        {
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(SpotData.latitude, SpotData.longitude),
                            map: map,
                            title: SpotData.hoverOver,
                            icon: {
                                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                strokeColor: SpotData.strokeColor,
                                strokeOpacity: SpotData.strokeOpacity,
                                strokeWeight: SpotData.strokeWeight,
                                fillColor: SpotData.fillColor,
                                fillOpacity: SpotData.fillOpacity,
                                scale: 5 }
        });
            spotsArray.push({ SpotID: SpotData.spotID, Spot: Spot });
            dataLayer.add(Spot);
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: A marker does exactly the opposite of what you say it does. It does **not** resize with the map, ie. it always has the same size, whatever zoom level you are using. If that's not what you want, you can use the [Circle class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle).

Comment: To clarify- The marker resizes in reference to the actual latitude and longitude measurements. 
It remains the same size in reference to the map screen size.

I am looking for a way for the small dot to remain the same size in reference to the latitude and longitude. I have looked into the circle class and those do not appear to be circles on the map. They have rough edges..

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to show what you have tried, post your code and narrow down your question to one problem. `Circle` *could* be the way to go. `Marker` too. Or both. Markers icons can be resized. You will probably need a [Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer). And why not [Heatmaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap). That should be enough ideas to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for suggestions to get started. I attempted to do this with Circles but when you get down to the close zooms they do not appear to be circles. I will post some code of the implementation with Markers when I get that coded. Thanks for your direction.

Comment: The option I am going to go with is a marker with an icon of a circle.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question. But If you are looking for **dynamic styling** this might help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Google Maps</title>
<style type="text/css">
#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var map = null;
    var dataLayer = null;
    function init() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center : {
                lat : 12.931,
                lng : 77.59180
            },
            zoom : 1
        });
        map.addListener('zoom_changed', zoomChange, this);
        dataLayer = new google.maps.Data({
            map : map
        });
        dataLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
        dataLayer.loadGeoJson('yourJsonFilePath.json');
    }
    function styleFunction(feature) {
        if (feature.getGeometry()) {
            var fillColor = null;
            var scale = null;
            switch (map.getZoom()) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                fillColor = "#0000ff";
                scale = 40;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                fillColor = "#00ff00";
                scale = 30;
                break;
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                fillColor = "#ff0000";
                scale = 20;
                break;
            case 12:
            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
                fillColor = "#ff00ff";
                scale = 10;
                break;
            default:
                fillColor = "#ffff00";
                scale = 5;
            }
            return {
                icon : {
                    path : google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    fillColor : fillColor,
                    fillOpacity : 1,
                    strokeWeight : 1,
                    strokeColor : fillColor,
                    scale : scale
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function zoomChange(event) {
        dataLayer.setStyle(styleFunction);
    }
</script>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&key=APIKey&callback=init"></script>
```

**EDIT**

In the style function instead of hardcoding the fill color you can get it from the feature property if you have in the json data as below

```
function styleFunction(feature) {
    if (feature.getGeometry()) {
        var fillColor = feature.getProperty("color");
        var scale = null;
        switch (map.getZoom()) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            scale = 40;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
            scale = 30;
            break;
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
            scale = 20;
            break;
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
            scale = 10;
            break;
        default:
            scale = 5;
        }
        return {
            icon : {
                path : google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                fillColor : fillColor,
                fillOpacity : 1,
                strokeWeight : 1,
                strokeColor : fillColor,
                scale : scale
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here **color** is the property which will be in each feature

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will look into this and get back to you.

Comment: See [Marker Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) might give some hint for you. If are interested check it out.

Comment: After looking at your code it makes sense. the only trouble is the color of the icon is determined by some JSON data. and the scale of icon is the only thing that is supposed to change on zoom. Is there a way to only change the scale not the colors?

Comment: Of course you can do that, Take color based on the feature property and handle scale based on the zoom value